# Traffic spikes - elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the best way to deal with traffic spikes on elastic beanstalk? In my experience this does not seem to scale quickly enough i.e. the new instances take a few minutes to get going.

Should I be doing some more calculations to optimise the scaling process?

Is there a formula for working these thing out?

Comment: Is your problem "real". I mean do you really have users with white pages instead of website, or whatever your system is delivering? On avarage solution, this situation would just never happened. If you have somethng very speciall, then you should be also able to estimate the time when resources will be needed and increment minium quantity of nodes for that period, by some automated scripting scheduled from outside...

Comment: just following up on this - we have actually chosen use an elastic load balancer with an auto-scaling group. I worked out maths for the auto-scaling as in the auto-scaling group the health of the EC2s in the group is monitored - if you determine how long a new EC2 instance takes to boot you can then work out when you should get it to start booting based on the resources being used by the any struggling instances - so if the CPU gets to say 70% and stays over that for more than a minute for example then you start the auto scaling process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it takes 5-10 minutes (depending on the stack you're using; not counting Windows instances) to launch a new Beanstalk instance via CloudFormation, install and configure the environment software, add the instance to the load balanced cluster, deploy your application code, and run any of your `.ebextensions`. (All of which you can follow along with by watching the event log for the environment, or the log for the CloudFormation template executing in the background.)

There are a couple of ways to handle this:

1. Use larger instances that won't *need* to scale-out so quickly.
2. Tweak your Auto Scaling triggers for your environment (via the AWS Console, web service API, or CLI tools) so that scale-up happens sooner. That way you'll have the extra capacity by the time the existing servers get maxed-out.

Comment: are there any figures that can help with tweaking the autoscaling?